# node-red - Node Credentials

Tags: credentials, node-red

Within a node-red flow I have a CassandraDatabase node with a user and pass. When I export the flow these credentials are not contained in the json, instead a flows_cred.json file appears with an encrypted string:

{"$": "df28.......

... however if I copy this file out and try to bring up my node-red instance elsewhere I get the following at startup:

[warn] Error loading credentials: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ï¿½ in JSON at position 0

... followed by a repeating "AuthenticationError: Authentication provider not set", message. Indeed the credentials have not been picked up by the node-red flow and so I must input manually again.

Anyone know the trick to allowing me to export the credentials successfully?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The credentials file (`flows_cred.json`) is encrypted by default to ensure its contents cannot be easily read.

Node-RED generates a random key for the encryption if you do not provide one in your settings file. If the second instance of Node-RED doesn't have the same encryption key, it won't be able to decrypt the file.

Here are the steps you need to resolve this.

1. edit your `settings.js` file and add a `credentialSecret` property with a whatever string value you want. If you want to disable encryption, set its value to `false`.

   ```
   credentialSecret: "my-random-string"
   ```
2. Restart Node-RED and deploy a change - this will trigger Node-RED to re-encrypt your credentials with your chosen key (or disabling encryption if set to false).
3. You can then copy your flow/credential file to a second instance, just make sure you give it the same `credentialSecret` value in its settings file.

Note that once you set `credentialSecret` you cannot change its value.

Comment: This also works when you run a docker container of node-red. You need to use a volume, for example `/home/user/node_red_data:/data` and in that `/home/user/node_red_data`, you will see many new files like `flows.json` that saves the flows of the container, and among the files is also the `settings.js` where you can uncomment the `//credentialSecret: "a-secret-key",` and change to your own string.

Comment: What is being used under the hood for encryption? Want to try to manually configure the credentials on different instances