# Node-Red: Deploy flow via Admin HTTP API containing credentials in nodes properties

Tags: rest, node-red

I try to deploy a flow via [Admin HTTP API](https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/) containing credentials in nodes properties. In my case it's a node of type [mqtt-broker](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-mqtt-broker). The security tab contains a property `user` which I try to put within the API call.

This property is stored in `flows_<hostname>_cred.json`. Like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270905/node-red-node-credentials) stated this file could be [encrypted](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/wiki/Design:-Encryption-of-credentials). In my case in `settings.js` it's set to `credentialSecret: false`.

Is it possible to pass values stored in `flows_<hostname>_cred.json` within the Admin HTTP API? Or is the only method replacing the file locally?

**Edit**

Test flow I sent to `https://127.0.0.1:1880/flows`, returns HTTP code 204.

```
[
    {
        "id": "f71b8c17.05ad3",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "Flow 1",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "baa95a0d.e490e",
        "type": "mqtt in",
        "z": "f71b8c17.05ad3",
        "name": "",
        "topic": "",
        "qos": "2",
        "datatype": "auto",
        "broker": "e8482c08.9858f",
        "x": 120,
        "y": 180,
        "wires": [
            [
                "bd237434.8030a"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "bd237434.8030a",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "f71b8c17.05ad3",
        "name": "",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "false",
        "x": 320,
        "y": 180,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "e8482c08.9858f",
        "type": "mqtt-broker",
        "z": "",
        "name": "test",
        "broker": "test",
        "port": "1883",
        "clientid": "",
        "usetls": false,
        "compatmode": true,
        "keepalive": "60",
        "cleansession": true,
        "birthTopic": "",
        "birthQos": "0",
        "birthPayload": "",
        "closeTopic": "",
        "closeQos": "0",
        "closePayload": "",
        "willTopic": "",
        "willQos": "0",
        "willPayload": ""
    }
]
```

This does not work for me if I add `"user": "TEST"` in `e8482c08.9858f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't directly pass data to the creds file, this is handled for you by the runtime.

You need to add the creds attributes to the matching nodes in the flow you then post to the admin api. They will then be stripped out, encrypted and added to the creds file.

So for the mqtt-broker config node you would add the `user` and `password` fields in a field called credentials. As described in the docs here https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/credentials

Comment: Packing into `"credentials": {...}` works :). https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/credentials If you enrich your answer with this info it will be the correct one :) Ty

Comment: Doh, knew I'd missed something. Edited